# Returning 1 in LowLevelMouseProc doesn't suppress the key in other programs

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to write a Teamspeak 3 plugin that suppresses mouse 4 and 5 for other programs using `SetWindowsHookEx` with `WH_MOUSE_LL`. Knowing that Mumble pretty much does this, I downloaded the source code and rummaged through it. So far I've managed to get the callback to work globally with the xbuttons(mouse 4 and 5), but I can't seem to get it to suppress it for other programs despite returning 1. Google Chrome for example still insists on going back when I press mouse 4, which Mumble has no issues preventing using the same method as I am.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS | GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT, (wchar_t *) &MouseCallback, &hSelf);
hMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseCallback, hSelf, 0);
```

And the callback:

```
if(wParam == WM_XBUTTONDOWN)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"xbutton", L"xbutton", MB_OK); // Works
    return 1; // Doesn't seem to do anything different
} 
else
{
    return CallNextHookEx(hMouseHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Don't call MessageBox. That causes tour hook to take longer than 500ms which means that Windows will assume you returned 0.

Comment: @RaymondChen Good to know, but even without it still doesn't suppress it.